# Which port is the power supplier of CPU Fan

Tags: cpu

I'm DIY a PC and met issues like below:

[image]

I'm confused about the interface in black color and white color.
Which one is actually for CPU_FAN?

Comment: Should be listed in the manual, but the general convention is (and has been for decades) that the labels printed on the board are in the same order as the connectors. So white is CPU and black is optional for a 2nd CPU fan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one on the right in your picture. The respective positions of the labels (ie which label is to the left) correspond to the respective positions of the connectors.

Comment: But the left one is closer to the label "CPU_FAN", lol.

Comment: _"But the left one is closer to the label "CPU_FAN""_ All I can tell you is that this is a convention I've been seeing on circuit boards for decades. Literally decades. If there isn't room to put each label closest to its respective component (like "below" them in your picture) then you put the labels where you have room for them, and arrange them the same way the components are arranged.

Comment: I've seen, wired up and even designed several of my own boards. Often it is the case that we don't have the space to put the labels next to devices so we arrange them nearby in a way that mimics the actual layout of parts, generally matching their positions and relative layout. I would not be in any doubt that this is answer is correct, the positions of the text tells me that there are two connectors and that the one on the right is the CPU fan.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Thanks for the clarification, it makes sense.